# Scroll issue in axml Designer in Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android App using Xamarin.

I have axml file with scroll view.

When I was using Xamarin Studio I can scroll it down using scroller in Editor.

Now I using Visual Studio and I cannot scroll down my axml.

Maybe someone facing this problem too? 
How I can solve it?

[image]

Comment: It's not development problem.

Comment: What problem is it? With visual studio?@ad1Dima

Comment: As i understand, there is no problem in your app or in your code. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. I think problem with visual studio. I can edit axml code but, I cannot scroll down to see what modified @ad1Dima

Comment: So it's not good topic for SO. Try to ask at https://forums.xamarin.com

Comment: Already done. I think maybe someone facing this problem too

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

How to solve this problem:

You need to update Xamarin in Alpha Channel. 
To change the updates channel in Visual Studio, navigate to the Tools menu and select Options. In the left panel of the Options window, scroll down and open the Xamarin options.Select either Other to open the panel.From the panel, choose the channel Alpha, and click Check Now to check for updates